# Why isn't there a minus sign in Ohm's law, $V = IR$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage, conventions, notation

Suppose current runs through a resistor from left to right, and we define the left-to-right direction as positive.

Then from left to right, the potential decreases. So $V,$ the voltage across the resistor (defined as the electric potential at the right of the resistor minus the electric potential at the left of the resistor), is negative, while $I,$ the current through the resistor, is positive. So it would seem $V = -IR$ is the correct relationship, but I don't recall ever seeing Ohm's law written this way. Why not?

(For example, in the introductory textbook I have on hand, Ohm's law is derived using $E = V/\Delta L,$ even though, in the previous chapter, the book writes $E_x = -\Delta V_x/\Delta x.$ [1] The intermediate book I have on hand argues that $V$ and $I$ must be proportional, saying "$V$ is the line integral of $\mathbf{E}$ on a path through the conductor...", but it would seem more appropriate to say "$V$ is the negative of the line integral of $\mathbf{E}$..." The book defines $V$ as "the difference in potential between those terminals" without specifying the direction. [2])

[1] *Physics*, Resnick, Halliday, and Krane, 5ed. equations 29-12 and 28-37

[2] *Electricity and Magnetism*, Purcell and Morin, 3ed. text before equation 4.12

Comment: Are you sure what V represents?  If it is a "drop" in potential then Ohm's law is providing the magnitude.

Comment: I'm not sure of anything, but I find the references I've consulted unclear, so I'm asking.

Comment: I thought this was just because $V$ was defined here as the voltage drop, i.e. the voltage on the left minus the voltage on the right. Kirchoff's loop rule is usually written in terms of voltage drops, too.

Comment: I guess that could be, but then voltage drop and voltage would share the same symbol, $V$. How is a student to know whether $V$ means voltage or voltage drop, aside from lots of experience? Sources like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law_(KVL) don't say they're using voltage drop for $V$, it's actually explicitly voltage if you look at the derivation.

Comment: With migration, diffusion and convection flux, with only migration flux one has Ohm's law (current equals |valence| times elementary charge times mobility times number density times electric field), if my notes are correct.

Comment: *"So V, the voltage across the resistor (defined as the electric potential at the right of the resistor minus the electric potential at the left of the resistor)"* -  According to the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention), the electric current enters the positive labelled terminal of a resistor.  You've chosen the opposite convention.  Why?

Comment: Because I never heard of that convention, it isn't explained in the references I checked, and its choice of defining the positive direction to be different directions for $i$ and $v$ is very strange.

Comment: the right answer is of course: convention and textbook inertia, but you are correct, $V=IR$ has a misleading sign convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer lies in the fact that resistors are not the only components in an electronic circuit.

Consider the following circuit.

[image]

Following the path of the electric current (positive charges), $V=\int \vec E \cdot d \vec l$ is **negative** for component $A$ and **positive** for component $B$.

> *What does that mean?*

It means that when positive charges go through component $A$, work is done **on** the positive charges and when the positive charges go through component $B$, work is done **by** them.

In simple terms, this can be interpreted as $A$ being a source of electrical energy, and $B$ being a sink of electrical energy. If $A$ is a photocell, the light is being converted into electrical energy, and if $B$ is an LED, then electrical energy is being converted into light.

> *For both components, the power is $|VI|$, so how does one
>   differentiate between these two components?*

A sign convention is introduced which is usually the **passive sign convention**, which then results in the electrical power produced in component $A$ being negative (a source of electrical energy) and that in component $B$ being positive (a sink of electrical energy).

There is another convention which is used and that is the **active sign convention** which makes the power of sources of electrical energy positive and that of sinks of electrical energy negative. For example, this is used when generators are sold; you buy a $(+)1\,\rm kW$ generator not a $-1\,\rm kW$ one.

The difficulty with running both conventions together, the passive for sinks and the active for sources, is that some circuit elements can be a source (battery connected to a bulb) or a sink (battery being recharged).

The passive sign convention is the one most commonly used, and then for a resistor, $V=IR$ with the current flowing from a high potential to a lower potential where $V$ is the drop in potential (in the direction of the current) across the resistor, i.e. a positive quantity.

Answer (score 5):

In the comments, Hal Hollis pointed to the ["passive sign convention"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention).

The passive sign convention is defined like this:

[image: passive sign convention diagram, from wikipedia]

So it is simply taken as a definition that the positive direction for current is the opposite direction as the positive direction for voltage. With this convention, $V=IR$ is the correct equation.

Comment: So, the sign to be given to $ V = \Delta V = V_f-V_i $ is what is obtained by proceeding in the opposite direction to the current?  In this way in the resistors $ V> 0 $ and with the generators we have (usually) $ V <0 $? @Mark Eichenlaub

Answer (score 0):

I think it's all a matter of definition. Electric current's direction is just defined as the direction in which (effective) positive charge carriers move. Positive charges move from the higher voltage points to lower-voltage points, so a flux variable (current) defined in that direction would be positive. You can, for example, define "current"'s direction as the direction in which electrons travel, and write V = -IR.

Comment: How are you defining $V$?

Comment: @Mark V is the electric potential difference, which equals integral of the Electric field (dl) between the two points.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "electric potential difference"? What are you subtracting from what? Suppose that at point $A,$ the electric potential is $0\;\mathrm{V}$ and at point $B,$ the electric potential is $1\;\mathrm{V}.$ Then what is the "electric potential difference" from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: @Mark I mean, if you integrate the electric field on any arbitrary path from point A to point B, it gives you V. In your example, integral of E(x,y,z) from A to B (dl) would equal 1.

Comment: No, that's wrong. If you do a line integral of the electric field from $A$ to $B,$ you get $-1$ times (potential at $B$ minus the potential at $A$).

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub it is just a matter of definition. In Ohm's law $V = V_\text{in} - V_\text{out}$ where "in" and "out" are the points where the current enters and leaves the resistor. Of course you *could* define it the other way round and insert minus signs everywhere, but that's the way it is. The definition "works" for simple examples, e.g. (using everyday language) if you connect a $6$ ohm resistor across the terminals of a $12$ volt battery the current is $2$ amps, not $-2$ amps.

Comment: So the textbook I cited, for example, in chapter 28, $V$ is used to indicate the electric potential, and for example $\nabla V = -\mathbf{E},$ but in the very next chapter $V$ is used to indicate $-1$ times the quantity $V$ was used for in the previous chapter (but for differences in it, not for the quantity itself), and the authors simply neglected to mention that they were inserting a negative sign into the definition between chapters? And that's just the way it is done? And "voltage" just takes on different meanings, related by a negative sign, depending on the context?

Comment: @Mark If you define "V" as the electric potential, then the Ohm's law would be delta(V) =  IR. In fact I remember from high school that it was confusing that we showed both electric potential and its difference by "V". It's just a matter of notation.

Comment: The. change. in. the. electric. potential. goes. the. opposite. direction. from. the. current. I don't know how to say this in a way you'll get it. They go the opposite direction. If the electric potential increases from left to right (positive change in electric potential), the current goes from right to left (negative current). They. have. opposite. signs.

Comment: @Mark How are you defining "current" then?

Comment: Direction of positive charge carriers, same as literally everyone ever.

Comment: @ Suppose we have a uniform field (E) which  goes from left to right. So the voltage is higher at the left side. The E would guide a positive charge (a positron for example) from left to right, since the electrostatic force on a positive charge is in the direction of the field. So the positive current would be from left to right by definition. What's the problem? I don't see opposite signs.

Comment: Suppose left to right is positive in your example. The potential is higher on the left side. The voltage is negative, because the electric potential goes down from left to right. If you go from a high number to a low number, the change is negative. $I$ is positive (positive charges to the right) and $V$ is negative (electric potential decreases to the right).

Comment: @Mark As I mentioned, here V is in fact ΔV, which could be either V2 - V1 or V1 - V2. You can define it however you want, people are just more comfortable to use the  ΔV = IR  form.

Comment: So you claim that the definition here is wrong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage#Definition_as_potential_of_electric_field?

Comment: @There is no problem with that definition, but yes, if you use that definition for the Ohm's law, it would be ΔV = -IR.

Comment: Can you find a single reliable source that defines the term "voltage" explicitly making it clear that they are defining $\Delta V_{AB} = \oint_A^B \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}$, without the negative sign?

Comment: $\int_a^b E\cdot dl = \int_a^b -\nabla\phi\cdot dl= -\int_a^b \nabla\phi\cdot dl=-(\phi(b)-\phi(a))=\phi(a)-\phi(b)$ ? Is this same a in minus out?

Comment: Emil, if I understand you correctly, yes, that would be defining voltage across an element as "in minus out" rather than "out minus in".

Answer (score 0):

There is a minus sign in $\vec J = \sigma \vec E$ and $\vec E = - \vec \nabla V$: the current goes down the voltage gradient. However, V in Ohm's law is not the potential but the potential drop caused by the resistor. I am all in favour of $\Delta V = -IR$. Yes, I changed my story ...

Comment: Do you have any reference corroborating that $V, I,$ and $R$ are scalars without direction? In that case, how could a circuit analysis with Ohm's law ever tell someone which direction the current was running through a particular circuit element?

Comment: Negative voltages and negative current flows are quite ordinary when analyzing an electronic circuit. The value of a "resistor" component always is a non-negative constant, but there are electronic components (e.g., a tunnel diode) and combinations of electronic components that behave like a negative-valued resistor over some limited range of currents and voltages.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. $R$ is a constant, and we have variables $V \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I \in \mathbb{R}$ where $V$ stands for the change in potential between two points and $I$ is the current from the current vector $\vec{I} = I \;\hat{u}$. So $V$ and $I$ are just some numbers, positive or negative. Ohm's law should be stated $V = -IR$ as you say.

Draw a number line on a sheet of paper as you would in algebra class. The positives are pointing in some direction. You could have drawn the positives in another tilted direction. You could even draw a curvilinear number line. A curvilinear number line has no fixed direction (each point on the line has an instantaneous positive direction), but it still has the sense of a single orientation. A curved number line is still one-dimensional from this standpoint.

Because of this (circuits are curvy), my guess is that Ohm's law is written as $|V| = |I|R$ (from my definitions of $V,I$ above) because there is no fixed direction (current is moving in this direction, then this direction, then down, etc).

Comment: (also, potential doesn't have a direction, nor does voltage. But voltage is measured in a "direction". Once you pick an orientation, let $V$ and $I$ be variables with respect to that orientation and let the math do the work for you)