# Why do we ignore the negative sign of self induction while considering inductors in an AC circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I have been taught that  the back EMF in a coil as per Lenz's law is

$$
e =-L \frac{di}{dt}
$$

Then why is that during circuit analysis of AC circuits, we consider the e across inductors to be 
$$
e=L \frac{di}{dt}
$$

Comment: maybe because we move it to the *other* side

Comment: @hyportnex, I don't think that's the case because I saw several articles where this was the formula given for inductance, standalone.

Comment: I thought you were asking about the role of the negative sign in Kirchhoff's loop equation (KVL), ie., in circuit analysis

Comment: Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452935/why-isnt-there-a-minus-sign-in-ohms-law-v-ir).

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we ignore the negative sign of self induction while considering
>   inductors in an AC circuit?

In circuit analysis, it is the *voltage* across the inductor, measurable with a voltmeter, that is of interest and that voltage is *opposed* by the inductor emf.  For an ideal inductor we have

$$v_L = L\frac{di_L}{dt} = -\mathcal{E}$$

That is, the inductor *emf* and the inductor *voltage* are distinctly different.  The inductor emf is due to the non-conservative electric field associated with a time varying magnetic field.  The inductor voltage is due to the conservative field associated with the difference in charge density at the inductor terminals.

Note that in the case of a non-ideal inductor with non-zero series resistance $r$, the voltage across also includes the voltage across this resistance:

$$v_L = L\frac{di_L}{dt} + ri_L \ne -\mathcal{E}$$

Comment: Superb answer !