# $\Delta P=QR $ in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Seems like a stupid question but I think that how $\Delta P$ can be negative?! Both $$ (flow) and $R$ (resistance) are positive and also for flow we need a pressure gradient which means the second pressure should be lower than the first pressure therefore $\Delta P$ should be negative. ‍‍‍ What am I doing?

Comment: You need to provide a specific example of what you are talking about for your question to be answerable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am fairly sure that you write $V=IR$ for the electrical equivalent equation?

Comment: That’s right Farcher , actually in our books before this first says Ohm’s law then base on that says this law, which I don’t know its name.

Comment: Think of pressure as a force (over area) and the then the direction of the force is the same as that of the flow of fluid?

Comment: Yes Farcher, I think you say that I imagine a tube ,then have a section of it, then what you says come true, but how can I say fluids flow base on their pressure gradient when delta p in this formula can’t be negative at least for me, thank you for your attention 

Answer (score 1):

Its just a matter of convention which direction voltage/pressure difference is calculated. When using Ohms law in a circuit, youre supposed to follow the so called "passive sign convention". As the law in your question is analogous to Ohms law, the same convention is applied. See [Why isn't there a minus sign in Ohm's law, $V = IR$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452935/why-isnt-there-a-minus-sign-in-ohms-law-v-ir)